# How to smooth low-res sampling of noise for voxel terrain

Tags: terrain, voxels, minecraft-modding, interpolation, perlin-noise

I am attempting to create a new terrain generator as part of a minecraft mod, which works very well if it samples at the full terrain resolution (16x256x16 voxels per terrain chunk). This is extremely laggy, so i attempted using a lower-resolution sample, x4x64x4, with an extra one sample on each positive axis to interpolate with (5x65x5, representing 20x260x20 space).

It all works fine until i try to smooth out the resulting 4x4x4 cubes of terrain. I have tried interpolating the noise value (0.0 to 2.0) of each block with the value next to it along each positive axis, each value weighted by how close the block is to it.

The result has some smoothing, but some of it seems to be rotated 90 degrees, and some areas are unsmoothed. I know this is possible, minecraft does it internally (the code is illegibly obfuscated and messy, about half a page, 20 variables and 6 loops).

Does anyone have any ideas about a reliable method for smoothing, only knowing the contents of the chunk and one sample to the north/east/top?

my current noise array generator:

```
protected double[] getNoise(float x, float z)
{
 // get a rough noisemap every 4 blocks, 1 more past the edge to round with
 double[] n = new double[1625]; // x65x5x5 3D space in order y,x,z  represents one chunk at 1/4 precision (1024 blocks plus 601 blocks padding along the positive-axis sides for rounding. Minecraft uses 825 doubles internally, 5x33x5)

 for(int lx = 0; lx < 5; ++lx)
   for(int lz = 0; lz < 5; ++lz)
   {
     // some extra noise that controls terrain thickness along Y
     double m = 32+(1f+SimplexNoiseGenerator.getNoise( (x+(lx*4))/256, (z+(lz*4))/256) )*32;

     for(int ly = 0; ly < 65; ++ly)
     {
       n[ (ly*25) + (lx*5) + lz ]= ( 1f+SimplexNoiseGenerator.getNoise( (float)(x+(lx*4))/512f, ((float)ly*4)/m, (float)(z+(lz*4))/512f ) ) * (1.5f-(Math.abs(32f-ly)/32f) ) ;
     }
   }
   return n;
}
```

Someone posted this on stack overflow, it is exactly the same problem and seems to be unresolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852194/smooth-lower-resolution-voxel-noise

Comment: I just answered pretty much the same question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124543/how-do-i-perform-interpolation-between-noise-values-sampled-at-a-lower-resolutio Hope it helps.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion myself, about a month ago. I had tried and failed to use trilinear interpolation previously, it turned out i just had the Y and Z swapped. It looked quite interesting.